# Unable to pipinstall pytest-flask as a dev dependency

Tags: python, pytest, pipenv

I am trying to install `pytest-flask` with pipenv as a dev dependency, since it is not needed at runtime.  when I do so, it fails:

```
pipenv install pytest-flask --dev
Installing pytest-flask...
Adding pytest-flask to Pipfile's [dev-packages]...
✔ Installation Succeeded 
Pipfile.lock (c1e323) out of date, updating to (64170d)...
Locking [dev-packages] dependencies...
Building requirements...
Resolving dependencies...
✘ Locking Failed! 
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2020.11.15/libexec/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 741, in _main
[ResolutionFailure]:       resolve_packages(pre, clear, verbose, system, write, requirements_dir, packages, dev)
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2020.11.15/libexec/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 709, in resolve_packages
[ResolutionFailure]:       requirements_dir=requirements_dir,
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2020.11.15/libexec/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 692, in resolve
[ResolutionFailure]:       req_dir=requirements_dir
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2020.11.15/libexec/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/utils.py", line 1403, in resolve_deps
[ResolutionFailure]:       req_dir=req_dir,
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2020.11.15/libexec/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/utils.py", line 1108, in actually_resolve_deps
[ResolutionFailure]:       resolver.resolve()
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2020.11.15/libexec/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/utils.py", line 833, in resolve
[ResolutionFailure]:       raise ResolutionFailure(message=str(e))
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]: Warning: Your dependencies could not be resolved. You likely have a mismatch in your sub-dependencies.
  First try clearing your dependency cache with $ pipenv lock --clear, then try the original command again.
 Alternatively, you can use $ pipenv install --skip-lock to bypass this mechanism, then run $ pipenv graph to inspect the situation.
  Hint: try $ pipenv lock --pre if it is a pre-release dependency.
ERROR: Could not find a version that matches werkzeug<2.0.0,>=0.7,>=2.0 (from moto==2.0.7->-r /var/folders/fq/3h122p7j77jbbfwhk7pvm7hw0000gn/T/pipenvupsq6d2mrequirements/pipenv-hwae0a1b-constraints.txt (line 13))
Tried: 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.3.1, 0.4, 0.4.1, 0.5, 0.5.1, 0.6, 0.6.1, 0.6.2, 0.7, 0.7.1, 0.7.2, 0.8, 0.8.1, 0.8.2, 0.8.3, 0.9, 0.9.1, 0.9.2, 0.9.3, 0.9.4, 0.9.5, 0.9.6, 0.10, 0.10.1, 0.10.2, 0.10.2, 0.10.4, 0.10.4, 0.11, 0.11, 0.11.1, 0.11.1, 0.11.2, 0.11.2, 0.11.3, 0.11.3, 0.11.4, 0.11.4, 0.11.5, 0.11.5, 0.11.6, 0.11.6, 0.11.7, 0.11.7, 0.11.8, 0.11.8, 0.11.9, 0.11.9, 0.11.10, 0.11.10, 0.11.11, 0.11.11, 0.11.12, 0.11.12, 0.11.13, 0.11.13, 0.11.14, 0.11.14, 0.11.15, 0.11.15, 0.12, 0.12, 0.12.1, 0.12.1, 0.12.2, 0.12.2, 0.13, 0.13, 0.14, 0.14, 0.14.1, 0.14.1, 0.15.0, 0.15.0, 0.15.1, 0.15.1, 0.15.2, 0.15.2, 0.15.3, 0.15.3, 0.15.4, 0.15.4, 0.15.5, 0.15.5, 0.15.6, 0.15.6, 0.16.0, 0.16.0, 0.16.1, 0.16.1, 1.0.0, 1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.1, 2.0.0, 2.0.0
Skipped pre-versions: 1.0.0rc1, 1.0.0rc1, 2.0.0rc1, 2.0.0rc1, 2.0.0rc2, 2.0.0rc2, 2.0.0rc3, 2.0.0rc3, 2.0.0rc4, 2.0.0rc4, 2.0.0rc5, 2.0.0rc5
There are incompatible versions in the resolved dependencies:
  werkzeug<2.0.0 (from moto==2.0.7->-r /var/folders/fq/3h122p7j77jbbfwhk7pvm7hw0000gn/T/pipenvupsq6d2mrequirements/pipenv-hwae0a1b-constraints.txt (line 13))
  werkzeug>=0.7 (from pytest-flask==1.2.0->-r /var/folders/fq/3h122p7j77jbbfwhk7pvm7hw0000gn/T/pipenvupsq6d2mrequirements/pipenv-hwae0a1b-constraints.txt (line 10))
  werkzeug>=2.0 (from flask==2.0.0->pytest-flask==1.2.0->-r /var/folders/fq/3h122p7j77jbbfwhk7pvm7hw0000gn/T/pipenvupsq6d2mrequirements/pipenv-hwae0a1b-constraints.txt (line 10))
```

When I try installing it as a runtime dependency, it works just fine:

```
pipenv install pytest-flask
Installing pytest-flask...
Adding pytest-flask to Pipfile's [packages]...
✔ Installation Succeeded 
Pipfile.lock (c1e323) out of date, updating to (6421b4)...
Locking [dev-packages] dependencies...
Building requirements...
Resolving dependencies...
✔ Success! 
Locking [packages] dependencies...
Building requirements...
Resolving dependencies...
✔ Success! 
Updated Pipfile.lock (6421b4)!
Installing dependencies from Pipfile.lock (6421b4)...
     ▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉ 0/0 — 00:00:00
```

Here is my Pipfile

```
[[source]]
name = "pypi"
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true

[packages]
Werkzeug = "<1.0"
#"0.16.1"
flask = "<=1.1.2"
#flask = "*"
flask-cors = "*"
flask-restplus = "*"
boto3 = "*"
bcrypt = "*"
flask-jwt-extended = "<4.0.0"
certifi = "*"
flask-sqlalchemy = "*"
flask-apscheduler = "*"
flask-migrate = "*"
coverage = "*"
pymysql = "*"
deep-security-api = "*"
sqlparse = "*"
importlib-metadata = "*"
requests = "*"
xmltodict = "*"
apscheduler = "*"
tornado = "==5.1.1"
python-dateutil = "*"
sqlalchemy = "==1.3.23"
elasticsearch = "*"
requests-aws4auth = "*"
gunicorn = "*"
gevent = "*"
python3-saml = "*"
xmlsec = "*"
pdpyras = "*"

[requires]
python_version = "3.7"

[dev-packages]
autopep8 = "*"
pylint = "*"
moto = "*"
pytest = "*"
black = "*"
atomicwrites = "*"
pre-commit = "*"
pytest-cov = "*"
pytest-mock = "*"
#pylint-flask-sqlalchemy = "*"
pylint-flask = "*"
mock-alchemy = "*"

[pipenv]
allow_prereleases = true
```

Environment:

- macOS
- pipenv version 2020.11.15
- Python 3.7.10

Comment: Based on the error output, I would guess that the dev dependency of moto is causing a werkzeug version issue. It cannot be both greater than and less than version 2.0.

Comment: @JoshJ why would it be OK as a runtime dep though?  "pipenv graph" shows that the pinned version of werkzeug should fine: werkzeug [required: <2.0.0, installed: 0.16.1]

Comment: werkzeug>=2.0 (from flask==2.0.0->pytest-flask==1.2.0

Try to install an earlier version of pytest-flask. From the error it looks like the recent version requires flask 2 which brings in the werkzeug version that is incompatible with your moto version.

Comment: @JoshJ I already tried that.  I installed an ancient version of pytest-flask and got the same problem.  I'm wondering if pipenv does not do so well in dep resolution for dev deps.